# docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version or Permission denied error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, dockeroperator

I am exploring [How to use the DockerOperator in Apache Airflow](https://marclamberti.com/blog/how-to-use-dockeroperator-apache-airflow/) tutorial. I have managed to set up airflow using docker-compose and able to access the `docker_dag` mentioned in the tutorial in my airflow browser. Here is the code for same.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
default_args = {
'owner'                 : 'airflow',
'description'           : 'Use of the DockerOperator',
'depend_on_past'        : False,
'start_date'            : datetime(2018, 1, 3),
'email_on_failure'      : False,
'email_on_retry'        : False,
'retries'               : 1,
'retry_delay'           : timedelta(minutes=5)
}
with DAG('docker_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="5 * * * *", catchup=False) as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_current_date',
    bash_command='date'
    )
    t2 = DockerOperator(
    task_id='docker_command',
    image='centos:latest',
    api_version='auto',
    auto_remove=True,
    command="/bin/sleep 30",
    docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
    network_mode="bridge"
    )
    t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_hello',
    bash_command='echo "hello world"'
    )
    t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

I am getting error while executing tast t2 (DockerOperator) below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 366, in execute
    self.cli = self._get_cli()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 397, in _get_cli
    base_url=self.docker_url, version=self.api_version, tls=tls_config, timeout=self.timeout
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
    f'Error while fetching server API version: {e}'
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
[2022-08-02, 09:02:50 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1420} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=docker_dag, task_id=docker_command, execution_date=20220802T085747, start_date=20220802T090250, end_date=20220802T090250
[2022-08-02, 09:02:50 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:97} ERROR - Failed to execute job 78 for task docker_command (Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')); 2516)
```

I tried many answer on github issues list and stackover like changing the  docker.sock file permission, restarting the docker and rebuilding docker images to run in new containers.

Sharing docker-compose file for the reference:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:2.3.3
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.3.3}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    # AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    # redis:
    #   condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  # redis:
  #   image: redis:latest
  #   expose:
  #     - 6379
  #   healthcheck:
  #     test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
  #     interval: 5s
  #     timeout: 30s
  #     retries: 50
  #   restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  # airflow-worker:
  #   <<: *airflow-common
  #   command: celery worker
  #   healthcheck:
  #     test:
  #       - "CMD-SHELL"
  #       - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
  #     interval: 10s
  #     timeout: 10s
  #     retries: 5
  #   environment:
  #     <<: *airflow-common-env
  #     # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
  #     # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
  #     DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
  #   restart: always
  #   depends_on:
  #     <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
  #     airflow-init:
  #       condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO && gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  # You can enable flower by adding "--profile flower" option e.g. docker-compose --profile flower up
  # or by explicitly targeted on the command line e.g. docker-compose up flower.
  # See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/
  # flower:
  #   <<: *airflow-common
  #   command: celery flower
  #   profiles:
  #     - flower
  #   ports:
  #     - 5555:5555
  #   healthcheck:
  #     test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
  #     interval: 10s
  #     timeout: 10s
  #     retries: 5
  #   restart: always
  #   depends_on:
  #     <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
  #     airflow-init:
  #       condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out we need to add this to docker-compose file and give right permission to it below

```
 - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

 sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

This is how common-part of docker-compose file looks like now:

```
volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Hi @iamabhaykmr, did you have to create the folders var/run/docker.sock also?

Comment: Hi @iamabhaykmr, did you give permissions into the docker-compose file or execute this in a separate terminal :  sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock

Answer (score 0):

After adding the below line in the docker-compose.yaml file

```
volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

, I am getting the below err:

```
111-airflow-init-1       | Database migrating done!
111-airflow-init-1       | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_limiter/extension.py:336 UserWarning: Using the in-memory storage for tracking rate limits as no storage was explicitly specified. This is not recommended for production use. See: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io#configuring-a-storage-backend for documentation about configuring the storage backend.
111-airflow-init-1       | airflow already exist in the db
111-airflow-init-1       | 2.8.0
111-airflow-init-1 exited with code 0
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Users/111/.docker/run/docker.sock': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/111/.docker/run/docker.sock: operation not supported
```